# Storing and using private keys with environment files? React

Tags: reactjs, security, next.js

I have a question to the stackoverflow community. I'm working with some payment stuff which has given me an private key that I would need to use in order to call their endpoints.

Storing the keys in environment is quite easy and I've done it before for smaller projects. But my question is.. Is that really the best way of doing it?

Since the project is built in NextJS (react), would you store the private keys in the environment and then collect them via the getServerSideProps function or?

I'm just interested in hearing your opinions and what would be the best way to solve this.  My goal is to have it as secure as possible. I'll therefore be more than happy to take an extra step or two to solve this.

What does the stackoverflow community think about this? How are YOU storing your private keys.

(I am googling in the backround and reading some blog posts. If I find something that makes sense, then I'll share it here for the next person with same questions as me)

Comment: To in any way shape or form give sensetive information like that to the client is an ABSOLUTE no. Don't even consider it.

Comment: @super Noted! How would you do it then? How are you storing your private keys and how do you fetch them?

Comment: Only the backend service that needs it has access to it. You never fetch it. You talk to your backend service with some sort of authentication system in place.

Comment: @super Got it. So what about storing the api key in the database and then with my api endpoint, I retrieve this key from the database to then use it in my api call? Yay or nay?

Comment: Decent. But there is most likely not much gain in storing the key in your database. If the data from you DB gets on the loose in some way the key is compromised. Depending on how you run/serve your backend there are safer ways to inject secrets to it with less exposure. If you simply have a server running a node backend app, and you are the only one with access to that server, passing an ENV variable to it is a simple option. Then you keep the sensetive info away from any database or github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Storing sensitive keys inside the application is a no no. What you can do is inject them into your application using environment variables. Then whenever you deploy your application, pass the keys as env variables.

Storing it in db is also wrong cause you do not want anyone with an access to db to also have access to your payment provider.

Refer this for more info
https://12factor.net/config

Answer (score 0):

`getServerSideProps` is the backend (to call APIs) in NextJS so it is secure to reference your environment variables here. Just ensure private keys don't appear in any client rendering. `getServerSideProps` are server rendered. I assume your blog searching pointed you in this direction -- but in case anyone else ends up here.

There is also this [tool](https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/) to confirm what code the client sees.